# How do I save audio files from Whatsapp to my Computer?

Tags: whatsapp, audio

When I plug my Windows Phone on my computer I see no directory to search Whatsapp files, I can only see the Images that my Whatsapp autosaves on my Image paste

Comment: How about Whatsapp web?

Comment: Never tried yet, I'll try it and give a feedback

Comment: Audio files downloaded are stored in apps internal storage. It cannot be accessed externally.

Comment: With whatsapp web is possible to save the audio files you receive, but I think the instant recordings nope

Answer (score 2):

But you can download the received audio files to your computer with the help of WhatsApp Web.

From https://7labs.heypub.com/mobile/export-save-whatsapp-audio.html:

> 1. Open WhatsApp on Windows Phone and tap on More (…) button in the bottom right corner of the screen and select "whatsapp web" option. A QR Code scanner will be launched.
> 2. Scan the QR Code displayed on your computer using the WhatsApp QR Code scanner. Once verified, you can access your WhatsApp chats from the registered computer.
> 3. Find a received audio in a particular conversation and click on the chat dialog to open the audio in preview mode.
> 4. In the preview mode, click on the Download icon on the top right corner to download the file.

Comment: You should summarize the content of the article, not just link to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the chatlist of the person
2. Tap on the contact
3. Tap the arrow beside media link and docs
4. Hover over the file you want to download, a tick button will appear, tap on that
5. After selecting the file you will see the download icon on the right hand side, tap on that

[image: Second Image]
[image]